# My wordpress website takes a lot to load. What shoukd I do to fix it?

Tags: wordpress, loading

I redesigned, approximately, a month ago this website: [www.3ndekmeme.com](http://www.3ndekmeme.com) in wordpress! and since then problems of loading have appeared. At times the loading goes perfectly fine and at otherthe website takes up to 15mins just to load properly. Could you find out what's the issue with me and how can I resolve it?

I tried deleting the cache, but it didn't fix the problem :/

Comment: If you haven't done so already, have a look at the [PageSpeed Insights report for your site](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-3ndekmeme-com/jl8wftp72d?form_factor=mobile) and work on fixing / improving all the performance issues listed there.

Comment: Improve your site by deferring and minifying your JavaScript, CSS, HTML files and manage your media files

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to have you here. However, your question might benefit from some improvements. Could you provide more context and be more specific about your issue? This will help you get better responses. Please read following guide: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Afterwards [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) your post and improve it. Happy coding!